# Reposition the tooltip when the mouse moves

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table that has many cells. Each cell has its own title.
What I want is to reposition the tooltip when the mouse moves.

JQuery:

```
   var $tooltip=$('<div id="tooltip"></div>').insertAfter('#myTable');
            var positionTooltip = function(event) {
      var tPosX = event.PageX;
      var tPosY = event.PageY + 20;
      $tooltip.css({top:tPosY,left:tPosX});// it seems to be not working.
           };
                 var showTooltip=function(event) {
           var title = $(this).attr("title");
           $tooltip.text(title).show();
                  positionTooltip(event);   
                }; 

  var fadout =function () { 
  $tooltip.hide(); 
  };
  $('.style13').hover(
  showTooltip,fadout
  );
```

CSS:

```
#tooltip {
display:none;                
background: #CCC630;
color: #AACBA;
text-align: left;
border-radius: 14px;
border: 2px solid white;
z-index:2;
margin-top:50px;
width:200px;
font-size:28px;
}
```

Right now the code is working well, the only thing is that the tootip is under the table because there is code. It is in the fixed position.

> "insertAfter".

How to modify the code or CSS to achieve my goal?

Thanks.

Comment: You aren't calling the positionTooltip function.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it. Just added it. But it is still under the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your positioning code is not working is that you are using "PageX" and "PageY", when you should be using "pageX" and "pageY".

```
  var $tooltip=$('<div id="tooltip"></div>').insertAfter('#myTable');
            var positionTooltip = function(e) {
      var tPosX = e.pageX;
      var tPosY = e.pageY + 20;
$tooltip.show();
      $tooltip.css({top:tPosY,left:tPosX});// it seems to be not working.
           };
                 var showTooltip=function(e) {
           var title ="title";
           $tooltip.text(title).show();  
                     positionTooltip(e);
                }; 
 var fadout =function () { 
  $tooltip.hide(); 
  };

  $('.style13').hover(
      showTooltip,fadout
  ).mousemove(positionTooltip);​
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/muY37/40/

Comment: Oh ho, should have observed that!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$tooltip.css({top:tPosY,left:tPosX});
```

try this out

```
$tooltip.animate({top:tPosY,left:tPosX},0);
```

Remove the `$tooltip` variable.

Complete code:

```
$(".style13").mouseenter(function(e) { 
var tPosx = e.pageX;
var tPosy = e.pageY + 20;
$("<div class = 'tooltip'>"+$(this).attr('title')+"</div>").appendTo('body').css({left: tPosx, top: tPosy}) }).mouseleave(function() { $(".tooltip").remove(); });
$(".style13").mousemove(function(e) {
var x = e.pageX;
var y = e.pageY;
$(".tooltip").animate({left: x+15, top: y+25},0);
});
```

Comment: It is not working, the title does show but the position is just below the table.

Comment: It cannot possibly be. Like I said, remove the `$tooltip` variable. So now `tPosx` and `tPosy` contains the x and y coordinates of the position in the cell where the mouse enters, how can this be below the table?